# Json model not binding in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular 1 app here.

I have this json file named data.json:

```
[
{
  "rejectionType": "REJECTION_1",
  "user": "ALL",
  "selected": false
},
{
  "rejectionType": "REJECTION_2",
  "user": "MALE",
  "selected": false
},
{
  "rejectionType": "REJECTION_3",
  "user": "FEMALE",
  "selected": false
}
]
```

In controller I do the following:

```
$http.get('data.json').then(function(response) {
var rejectionData = response.data;
myctrl.currentRejections = _.filter(rejectionData, function(item, index) {
  return _.contains(["ALL", "MALE"], item.user);
})
console.log("myCtrl.currentRejections:",myCtrl.currentRejections);
$("#modRejectionReason").modal("show");
});
```

The modal in the view looks like this:

```
<div id="modRejectionReason">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>
                <div ng-repeat="allrejections in myctrl.currentRejections">
                    <p>
                        <input type="radio" name="selected" ng-model="allrejections.selected" />
                        {{allrejections.rejectionType}}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" ng-click="myctrl.func()">OK</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And then in the controller I have this:

```
var declineInvite = function () {
console.log("myctrl.currentRejections:",myctrl.currentRejections);
}
```

In the log I see that when the modal appears, then the variable `myCtrl.currentRejections` is printed. And it is an array with all the filtered elements.
For each element I see that the field `selected` is false.

When I then check a radio button and then click on the `OK-button` the function `func` is triggered.
Even here the same data is printed in the console. However, for those radio buttons that have been clicked in the json the value for the field `selected` is undefined.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the radio buttons a value to set when they are checked.

```
<input type="radio" name="selected" ng-model="allrejections.selected" ng-value="true"/>
```

The problem with doing this in your current code is that the `selected:true` will never be unset, so I suggest adding a new value on the controller called `selectedRejection` and using that as the model and setting the value to the actual rejection object. Doing this means you can get rid of the selected property on your JSON data too!

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []).controller("MyCtrl", MyCtrl);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl() {
  var MyCtrl = this;
  MyCtrl.currentRejections = [{
      "rejectionType": "REJECTION_1",
      "user": "ALL",
      "selected": false
    },
    {
      "rejectionType": "REJECTION_2",
      "user": "MALE",
      "selected": false
    }
  ]

  MyCtrl.selectedRejection = null;

  MyCtrl.submit = function() {
    console.log(MyCtrl.selectedRejection)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="allrejections in MyCtrl.currentRejections">
      <p>
        <input type="radio" name="selected" ng-model="MyCtrl.selectedRejection" ng-value="allrejections" /> {{allrejections.rejectionType}}
      </p>
    </div>


    <button type="button" ng-click="MyCtrl.submit()">OK</button>
  </div>
</body>
```